# Bad notification for startForeground for Android 9

Tags: android, androidx, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

The foreground service notification works for android 8 but does not work on Android 9.  Application crashed  after I grant  all the permissions with an error message

`android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0)`

My manifest has permission  for foreground service

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

Code

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mScheduler = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification(R.string.notification_title, R.string.sensor_disconnected, R.drawable.ic_stat_disconnected));

    log(TAG, "Create Service");
}

public Notification getNotification(int title, int text, int icon) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder foregroundNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    foregroundNotification.setOngoing(true);

    foregroundNotification.setContentTitle(getText(title))
            .setContentText(getText(text))
            .setSmallIcon(icon);

    return foregroundNotification.build();
}

private void updateNotification(int title, int text, int icon) {
    Notification notification = getNotification(title, text, icon);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

private void removeNotification() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

private void setConnectionState(Boolean connected) {
    if (connected) {
        updateNotification(R.string.notification_title, R.string.sensor_connected, R.drawable.ic_stat_connected);
        Log.d("S: CONNECTION_STATUS", "sensor_connected");

        DateTime timestamp= new DateTime();

        HashMap<String, String> connectionStatus = new HashMap<>();
        connectionStatus.put(MOVISENS_CONNECTION_STATUS,"sensor_connected");
```